# Intersection of 2 lists which contain non-hashables

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to find the intersection of 2 lists when both lists contain non-hashables?

Basically, let's say I have the following lists (which I completely made up):

```
A = [<foo.bar object at 0x7f267c664080>, <foo.bar object at 0x7f267c664099>]
B = [<foo.bar object at 0x7f267c664080>, <foo.bar object at 0x123456789101>]
```

We can see that the first element of `A` is the same as the first element of `B`.

I can do the simple thing by creating a for loop:

```
intersection = []

for obj_a in A:
    for obj_b in B:
        if ( (obj_a == obj_b) and (obj_a not in intersection) ):
            intersection.extend(obj_a)
```

but I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient, cooler, or simpler way. For example, there is:

```
C = [1, 2, 3]
D = [3, 4, 5]
set(C).intersection(set(D))
```

...but obviously I can't use `set` or `frozenset` for non-hashables because I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: foo.bar
```

Is there anything like this for non-hashables?

Comment: `intersection = [x for x in A if x in B]`? Or implementing the `__hash__` magic method of your `foo.bar` object, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is what makes the `set` efficient. If you can't hash, then you can't take advantage of that efficiency - you have to compare every object with every other object and you get an O(n²) algorithm instead of an amortized O(n) one.

However, if you care only about object *identity* and not equality, then you can make dicts mapping the object ids to the objects, and take the intersection of the ids:

```
>>> class foo(object): pass
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> A = [foo(), foo(), f]
>>> B = [foo(), f, foo(), foo()]
>>> [a for a in A if id(a) in (set(map(id, A)) & set(map(id, B))]
[<__main__.foo object at 0x100a7e9d0>]
```

If you want a more code-efficient solution or you do care about object equality, then [@Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186008/15055) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using list comprehension: `intersection = [element for element in A if element in B` checks if two elements of the same *value* are there. For example, for `[1, 2, 3]` and `[0, 1, 5]`, it will return `[1]`.

Comment: This will return duplicates if an item exists twice.